# python/django for loop creating database populated with 0000-9999

Tags: python, django

Basically, i've created a view to populate my database with Serial models from 0000 to 9999. below is the code i'm using for the view.

```
def insert_serials(request):
    for i in range(0,10000):
    serial = Serial(i,False)
    serial.save()
    else:
    print 'The for loop is over'
```

what is the right way to do this, and i'm getting an IntegrityError, duplicate keys, my model defination is below:

```
class Serial(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    closed = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.serial)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/draw/serial/%s/" % (self.serial)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id field (implied by the absence of a PK definition in your model) is not being autonumbered correctly and therefore every INSERT after the first is failing with a duplicate id value.  What's your database?  Did you have Django create the table, or did you do it yourself?

Comment: hi, i'm using mysql and yes, Django created the table using syncdb and the def's in the models.py

Comment: this i think was the problem, i had to manually assign PK defination on the database.  There was another code problem, but this was what primarily wasn't causing the for loop to save after 1

Answer (score 1):

There may be positional default arguments, try using keywords:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def insert_serials(request):
    for i in range(0,10000):
        serial = Serial(serial=str(i),closed=False)
        serial.save()
    transaction.commit()
    print 'The for loop is over'
```

It's wrapped in a transaction should speed it up a bit.
See [transaction.commit_manually](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django-db-transaction-commit-manually) for details

Comment: this gave me a TransactionManagementError and only inserts one row, obviously i is not increasing, and the for loop ends after 1 record only.

Comment: why are you doing for else? I'm pretty sure else fires only if the for never executes, which will never happen.

Comment: I agree the 'else' statement there can be confusing, I'll remove it, but it should work fine.  

From the docs:
Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Comment: @monkut thanks for the heads up, I totally misunderstood what else did.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working on my site - Mac OS X, Python 2.6.3, django from trunk, sqlite3

I changed your view function code a bit, though -

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import Serial

def insert_serials(request):
    for i in range(0,10000):
        serial = Serial(i,False)
        serial.save()
    return HttpResponse("Serials are inserted")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `unique=False` in the `closed` field declaration.

Also, you're trying to put integers into a string field. You should do it like `Serial('%04d' % i, False)` to put values from `'0000'` to `'9999'`.

Comment: i did this, but the unique index seemed to be on my Serial field, so i removed the index from the database and it did in fact insert 9999 records but all with 0 as the serial, meaning i was always zero.